# How to stop a pandas dataframe splitting columns onto separate lines?

Tags: python, pandas, terminal

I'm running a python file from a `.bat` file that part way through prints a pandas dataframe. However it won't display all the columns and data in one row:

```
            date_time  id_  match_oc_id                tournament_name  \
0 2021-02-05 12:30:00  139      1421889  ITF M15 Nur-Sultan Men (hard)

   edge_threshold                              players target_bookie  \
0             0.1  Eric Vanshelboim vs Mats Rosenkranz  William Hill

      target_player  mkt_p_win  ogn_p_win  edge  target_odds  target_stake
0  Eric Vanshelboim       0.42       0.59  0.17         2.38          0.06
```

I've tried adding this to the beginning of the python file:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 20)
```

I've also tried making the terminal window bigger by adding this to the beginning of the `.bat` file:

```
mode con:cols=400 lines=75
```

No luck with either approach. Any ideas?

Comment: Play with `display.width`, default is `80`.

Comment: Superstar, thanks :-)